# Is it possible to initiate SCCM 2007 updates from the command line or powershell on client's computer?

Tags: command-line, powershell

Current Process:
1. RDP to client's machine
2. Install updates that are advertised in User Interface
3. Reboot

Issues:
1. We have to remote into one machine at a time, which is a nightmare.
2. We are not allowed to have these updates run automatically.
3. We are not allowed to download foreign software, but we can write it.

What would be the recommended way for remoting into multiple machines at a time and running the updates that are cached in the temporary folder? I've been researched this all night and it seems this problem is unique because of our limitations, most normal networks would just have the users automatically download the updates.

Comment: Psexec.exe ran from command line could be used to run the updates that downloaded to the ccm/cache folder

Comment: @ElTurner We have a pre-approved list of tools and these tools aren't currently allowed.